# Vlookup Importrange Array formula is not working

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using this formula and it is not working since i changed the column reference. Before it was working fine.

I do not know what mistake i have did. Your help will be appreciated.

[Formula Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/198_HZx-Drn3b9g3xkdUqwDwoPm3BFccgVyt2CcBsQLE/edit?usp=sharing)

[Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xUIHA6UIqS7II8mZttQSifcvMJy-l6tDiZmwv7fw5ls/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A501="",,iferror(vlookup(B3:B501&" "&C3:C501&" "&F3:F501&" "&G3:G501,query(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xUIHA6UIqS7II8mZttQSifcvMJy-l6tDiZmwv7fw5ls/edit#gid=462447817","Sheet1!A3:W500")),,22))),"select Col1,Col2 where Col1<>'' ",1),2,0),"NF")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In H3 try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B3:B501="",,vlookup(trim(B3:B501&" "&C3:C501&" "&text(F3:F501, "mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&G3:G501), {transpose(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xUIHA6UIqS7II8mZttQSifcvMJy-l6tDiZmwv7fw5ls/edit#gid=462447817","Sheet1!A3:W500"), "Select Col2, Col3, Col6, Col7")),,9^9)), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xUIHA6UIqS7II8mZttQSifcvMJy-l6tDiZmwv7fw5ls/edit#gid=462447817","Sheet1!W3:W500")} ,2,0)))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: thank you for posting the answer but these values are not same always `Average|Done|Not Done|Average|Medium|A\+` these can be anything i just posted the example data. In realty these are `comments`

Comment: Updated formula. Please try and see if it works?

Comment: I need one more help if you can please. Can we `"Sheet1!W3:W500")} ,2,0)))` extend this range which we takes from other sheet by matching columns. If there are more column like W,X,Y,Z i want to load their data together using above formula instead of just Column `W3:W500` @JPV i would appreciated your help.

Comment: Because right now above formula just load the W column data i want to put the range like `W3:AA500` so all data could be loaded in once

Comment: You should be able to change "Sheet1!W3:W500" to "Sheet1!W3:AA500" and use an array to return the columns you want. E.g: {2, 3, 4} instead of just '2'.